# How can I create a platform generator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a simple platform generator and I came up with this method:

`float space = Random.Range(0, distance);
 Instantiate(building, building.transform.GetChild(1).position  + new Vector3(building.transform.position.x,0,0)+ new Vector3(space,0,0), Quaternion.identity);`

But as expected, It just instantiates platforms based on the first platform's position. How can I get the position of the generated platform every time instead of just the first one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Instantiate` function returns the object it instantiates. You can get that object and access the position and rotation from it.

A global variable to hold the last instantied object:

```
public GameObject obj;
```

Instantiate and return the reference to the instantiated object:

```
obj = Instantiate(building, building.transform.GetChild(1).position
    + new Vector3(building.transform.position.x, 0, 0) + new Vector3(space, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

Access the position and rotation of the instantiated object:

```
Vector3 pos = obj.transform.position;
Quaternion rot = obj.transform.rotation;
```

---

If you need to use the position of the last instantiated object then just check if it `null`. If `null`, use the prefab original prefab position since there no instantiated prefab yet. If not `null` then use the last instantiated object position.

```
if (obj == null)
{
    //Use the original prefab position
    obj = Instantiate(building, building.transform.GetChild(1).position
       + new Vector3(building.transform.position.x, 0, 0) + new Vector3(space, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
else
{
    //Use last instantiated object position
    obj = Instantiate(building, obj.transform.GetChild(1).position +
        new Vector3(obj.transform.position.x, 0, 0) + new Vector3(space, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that i think the distance stacks on each other every time it instantiates a new platform. Distance keeps increasing after every instantiation.

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what you mean by *"the distance stacks on each other every time it instantiates a new platform"* but I just showed you how to *"get the position of the generated platform"*. The second part of my answer assumes you want to instantiate object with the position of the last instantiated object then add the random space variable....

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Unity. But from the cases where people made Windows Forms elements in a loop, I can give you this:

You create them in a loop. And each itteration is offset by (i * [platform width+gap between platforms])+offset from border from the next.

You could also keep the last platform around in a variable whose scope is outside of the loop. You just need to deal with it being empty (null) on the first itteration. And letting it run out of scope after the loop is done. Something like:

```
{
  Platform lastPlatform = null;
  for(...){
  }
}
```

I do hope there is some better, Unity specific solution.